# can't find node_modules after mv command

Tags: mv

I accidently moved my node modules to the wrong place

```
www 
--html
--node_modules
```

I wanted to move them into the html folder so I used this command

```
mv node_modules /html
```

now they have disappeared where did they go?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's look like you moved them to new directory on the root.
Try

```
ls -la /
```

You will probably see there a directory called html 
`/` this is the root directory of the filesystem.

Comment: Yep there it is Thanks.